# 1and1 won't accept my SQL

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, procedure

I use MySQL Workbench whilst developing on localhost and the following stored procedure works just fine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `follow`(IN in_follower INT(11), IN in_followee VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO follower (follower_id, followee_id)
VALUES (in_follower,(SELECT `user_id` FROM user WHERE `username` = in_followee));
END
```

When I try to create the procedure of 1and1's servers the SQL is rejected under the following error:

Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

What on earth?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), I think your syntax should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `follow`(IN in_follower INT(11), IN in_followee VARCHAR(45))
    INSERT INTO follower 
    (follower_id, followee_id)
    SELECT in_follower, `user_id` 
    FROM   user 
    WHERE  `username` = @in_followee);
END
```

I'm suprised your original syntax worked locally to be honest...

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Isn't that SELECT trying to get a column named "in_follower" from the user table?

Comment: @RichardG Did you try it? I haven't tested it, as I don't have MySQL available, but the principle is correct. It's selecting the **variable** `in_follower`, and the column `user_id` from the table `user`